# Website Preferences, Should i save it in Database Table?

Tags: php

I am little bit curious, i want to have ability to update the `Website name`, `logo (path)`, `copyright` from the Admin Panel of my website.

I am wondering, it will only require 1 row. I mean if form is updated then database table will be updated, its not like new data will be added to database table.
so for only 1 row of information, is it a good practice to make a table in database, or should i approach any other way like load data from file or something related to this.

Which way is more efficent and more reliable?

If anyone have experience in big CMS websites and want to share there views please, Share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually have a table called `config`. It looks pretty much like this:

`id | key | value`

In this way, I can store unlimited options into this table, for example:

`1 | copyright_text | Copyright 2014`

Then you can just retrieve this by using a query similar to:

`SELECT value FROM config WHERE key='copyright_text'`

Comment: then i guess i will have to use `foreach` loop if i want to get all the key values and store them in variables.
How do you do that?

Comment: If you want to get all settings, you can just do `SELECT * FROM config` and indeed then store them to variables. You can use PHP function `list()` to store it to seperate variables without needing a `foreach` loop, or you can `foreach` it and do something like this: `foreach ($config as $key => $value) { ${$key} = $value; }` - this way, `$config['copyright']` becomes `$copyright`.

Answer (score 1):

A common way used by CMS is to used a table called `config` for example where you have a key => value tuple.

Example:

```
name => Website Name
logo => http://path_to_logo/
copyright => Cop
date_format => mm/dd/yyyy
```

It allows you to keep all your dynamic configuration at the same place and to easily save and restore them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database we well as XML or json files to store website preference.